# Large non-deterministic delay when writing to pipe

Tags: c++, linux, pipe

I am experiencing intermittent delays when I `write` to an open FIFO pipe under linux, but only on one of two machines.

This is demonstrated by the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


uint64_t get_us() {
  timespec time;
  int ret;

  ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &time );
  if (ret!=0) {
        std::cerr << "Oh no, clock problem!\n";
        exit(1);
  }
  return time.tv_sec * 1000000 + time.tv_nsec/1000;
}

int main() {
  const time_t delay = 100000;
  char test[200];
  size_t len = 200;
  uint64_t prev_us, us, delta;
  int pipe_fd;
  uint64_t delta_sum=0;
  uint64_t min = 1000000;
  uint64_t max = 0;
  uint32_t count=0;

  std::cout << "Opening pipe....\n";
  pipe_fd = open("/tmp/tmp_pipe", O_WRONLY);

  std::cout << "Writing to pipe every " << delay << "uS.\n";

  prev_us = get_us();
  while (true) {
     write(pipe_fd, test, len);
     us = get_us();
     delta = us - prev_us;
     delta_sum+=delta;
     count+=1;
     if (delta < min)
       min=delta;
     if (delta > max)
       max=delta;
     if (count==1000000/delay) {
       std::cout << " ~second stats: " << min << " : " << delta_sum/count << " : " << max << "\n";
       delta_sum=0;
       count=0;
       min=1000000;
       max=0;
     }
     usleep(delay);
     prev_us = get_us();

  }
}
```

The program writes 200 bytes to a pipe at 10Hz, outputing the min/avg/max time for the call to write in 1 second windows. Before starting the program, in another terminal I run `mkfifo /tmp/tmp_pipe; cat /tmp/tmp_pipe > /dev/null`.

I expect the time to vary, but occasionally I see the call take ~ 100ms. I can't imagine such a delay is down to the scheduler, and I only see these spikes on one of two machines (both Intel, Linux 4.4.0).

Typical output:

```
Opening pipe....
Writing to pipe every 100000uS.
 ~second average: 6 : 6 : 12
 ~second average: 5 : 5 : 7
 ~second average: 5 : 6 : 9
 ~second average: 6 : 6 : 7
 ~second average: 6 : 6 : 7
 ~second average: 5 : 6949 : 69442
 ~second average: 5 : 6 : 7
 ~second average: 5 : 7 : 9
 ~second average: 6 : 6 : 7
```

Is this behaviour normal? What could cause such a delay?

Comment: on both machines same kernel with same parameters?

Comment: What's the target machine do with the data it gets from the pipe?  Pipe writes can stall if the system on the other end of the pipe is busy (and not actively listening to the pipe).

Comment: @BorisT yes, same.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm the reader is just cat into /dev/null. I tried other readers without change.

Comment: I tried the exact same code, but instead of writing to a pipe I wrote to a normal file. The same delay is apparent, suggesting it is not actually a pipe issue...